# Supabase procedure is working fine in sql terminal on it's website but when I try calling it in my nextjs application it doesn't work

Tags: next.js, supabase

Tables:

movies: [image]

directors: [image]

movie_director: [image]

create
or replace function get_director_info_2 (mid in integer) returns setof directors as $$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY
SELECT d.id, d.director_image, d.director_name, d.director_description
FROM directors d
JOIN movie_director md ON md.director_id = d.id
JOIN movies m ON md.movie_id = m.id
WHERE m.id = mid;
END;
$$ language plpgsql;

//When I call it.

SELECT * FROM get_director_info_2(2);

[image: The result]

**The code in next.js

(page.js)
**
*The following should provide an array of director's info, but that is not working, even though it is working in the sql terminal*

```
`
"use client"

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import supabase from '../../../config/supabaseConfig';
import Link from "next/link";

export default function movie_details({ params }) {

    const id = params.id;
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [directorData, setDirectorData] = useState([]);
    const [err, setErr] = useState(null);




    const fetchData = async () => {
        let { data: movies, error } = await supabase
            .from('movies')
            .select("*")
            .eq('id', id);

        setData(movies);
        setErr(error);
    }

// Write a function which calls a procedure called get_director_info_2 from supabase        
1. useEffect(() => {
        // Fetch director info first
        async function fetchDirectorInfo() {
            try {
              let { data, error } = await supabase.rpc('get_director_info_2', {
                mid:id // Replace with the movie_id you want to query
              });
          
              if (error) {
                console.error('Error:', error);
              } else {
                console.log('Data:', data);
                // Handle and process the data as needed
              }
            } catch (error) {
              console.error('Unexpected Error:', error);
              // Handle any unexpected errors
            }
          }
    
        fetchDirectorInfo();
    }, [id]); // This will trigger the effect when 'id' changes

    useEffect(() => {
        // Fetch data for movies
        fetchData();
    }, [directorData]); // This will trigger the effect when 'directorData' changes


    

};
`
```

One record of a specific director based on the movies_id, should have been the output.

Comment: You have row level security (RLS) on your movies table and when using the SQL editor in the Supabase dashboard it won't take the RLS into consideration so you get results. However when calling the same function from your NextJS code it will take RLS into consideration and if you aren't meeting the policy criteria then you won't get any results.